# Unexpected results in Entity Framework Core when using Skip and Take with Include

Tags: sql-server, razor, entity-framework-core

I am trying to load related entities using EF Core and then paginate the results.

When I use the code shown below with let's say `pageIndex=1` and `pageSize=20`, I get only two results:

```
var products = _context.IProductServices
                       .Include(p => p.ICatalogProductServices)
                           .ThenInclude(cl => cl.Catalog)
                       .Include(p => p.Category)
                           .ThenInclude(c => c.Parent).AsSplitQuery();

var paginatedProducts = await products.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                                      .Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

When I remove the include clauses, it works as expected and I get 20 results

```
var products = _context.IProductServices.AsSplitQuery();
var paginatedProducts = await products.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                                      .Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

Is this expected behaviour? It seems like `Skip` and `Take` don't work as expected. I am using Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 with SQL Server

Comment: Do you use Global Query filters? Anyway it can be required relation which after JOIN filter out records.

Comment: I don't use Global Query filters. It seems like Including Category is the problem. I guess I will use Join after the paging. Isn't ef core supposed to load related entities using include though? Category is a required relationship.

Comment: Make this relation non-required or correct database data.

Comment: You are right. I was not enforcing foreign key constraint between product and category thus some products were pointing to a category that no longer existed. After fixing my data to point to a correct category it seems to work correctly. Thanks for your help!